# Как перехватывать и отображать сообщение в TextView в фоновом режиме

Tags: java, android, android-studio, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать, чтобы при закрытии или при сворачивание приложения оно отлавливало сообщения и отображало в TextView? Ниже представлена программа реализации получения, отображения в активном режиме и Toast.makeText в фоновом режиме

AndroidManifest.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.danil.sms">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.danil.sms.MessageReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Метод по отправки сообщений

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Button btnSend;
        EditText tvMessage;
        EditText tvNumber;
        IntentFilter intentFilter;

        private BroadcastReceiver intentReciever=new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                TextView inTxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMsg);
                inTxt.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
            }
        };

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        btnSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        tvMessage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        tvNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);

}
    private View.OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String myMsg=tvMessage.getText().toString();
            String theNumber=tvNumber.getText().toString();
            sendMsg(theNumber, myMsg);
        }};

    private void sendMsg(String theNumber, String myMsg) {
        String SENT="Message Sent";
        String DELIVERED="Message Delivered";

        PendingIntent sentPI=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT),0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(DELIVERED),0);

        //myMsg-сообщение на отправку

        android.telephony.SmsManager sms= android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg,sentPI,deliveredPI);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        registerReceiver(intentReciever, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        unregisterReceiver(intentReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Метод выводу полученного сообщения на экран

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages;
        String str="";
        if (bundle!=null){
            Object[] pdus=(Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            messages=new SmsMessage[pdus !=null ? pdus.length:0];
            for(int i=0; i<messages.length; i++){
                messages[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) (pdus!=null ? pdus[i]:null));
                //1-адресс приходс сообщения
                str+=messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str+=": ";
                //2-само сообщение
                str+=messages[i].getMessageBody();
                str+="\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent broadcastIntent=new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", str);
            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда приложение (его активити) в фоне у вас нет никакой возможности гарантированно что-то там сделать, т.к. система может в любой момент прибить приложение.

Вам надо действовать иначе:

1. Сохраните где-то данные, полученные ресивером в фоне. Например в БД.
2. При старте активити извлекайте из БД все пришедшие в фоне сообщения и отображайте их.

Comment: ошибка при создании базы данных
 public DBHelper(BroadcastReceiver context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,
        DATABASE_VERSION);;
    }
Error:(34, 41) error: incompatible types: <anonymous BroadcastReceiver> cannot be converted to Context

Comment: @Medaf, зайдайте это в отдельном вопросе. Попытка выяснить проблему в комментариях приведёт к тому, что модераторам придётся комменты в чат перенести, а я в чаты не хожу)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801444/Ошибка-при-сохранении-данных-с-фонового-процесса-в-базу-данных-sqlite

Comment: [Google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801444/Ошибка-при-сохранении-данных-с-фонового-процесса-в-базу-данных-sqlite)